# Trouble reading key from XML file

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-core, .net-core, linq-to-xml

I am trying to get the "Command" element of a Windows scheduled tasks by parsing the relevant XML file

Ie,

```
var taskFile = $"{Environment.SystemDirectory}\\Tasks\\MyBackupTask";
```

That files looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<Task version="1.2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task">
  ...
  <Actions Context="Author">
    <Exec>
      <Command>C:\somepath\MyBackupTask.exe</Command>
    </Exec>
  </Actions>
</Task>
```

I am now trying to simply load and parse the file and get the Command value,
I can't get this to work, perhaps a namespace issue (which in this case can be safely ignored) ?
(Note that I don't want the namespace hardcoded into my path query as that may change between windows versions, I just want it to be ignored)

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(taskFile);
var el=xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("./Actions/Exec/Command"); // returns null
var el=xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("/Actions/Exec/Command"); // returns null
var el=xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("*[local-name()='Task']/Actions/Exec/Command"); // returns null
var el=xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("/*[local-name()='Actions']/Exec/Command"); // returns null
var el=xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("*:Task/Actions/Exec/Command"); // throws exception
var el=xdoc.Root.XPathSelectElement("/*:Actions/Exec/Command"); // throws exception
```

How is this done ?

(using .NET Core 3.1)

**EDIT:**

This works:

```
static string ValueAtPath(XElement root, string path) {
  path = String.Concat(path.Split('/').Select(x => $"/child::node()[local-name()='{x}']"));
  return root.XPathSelectElement(path)?.Value;
}

var command = ValueAtPath(xdoc.Root, "Task/Actions/Exec/Command");
```

by turning `"Task/Actions/Exec/Command"` into `"/child::node()[local-name()='Task']/child::node()[local-name()='Actions']/child::node()[local-name()='Exec']/child::node()[local-name()='Command']"`

Surely there's a better way ?

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/john_pollard/2005/11/12/using-selectsinglenode-or-selectnodes-on-xml-where-the-default-namespace-has-been-set/

Comment: thx @madreflection, I don't want the namespace hardcoded as in the link you posted as it may change between windows versions etc

Comment: If it changes, the path likely won't work, anyway. Hard-coding the namespace would be the least of your worries.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand your solution

Comment: The link has the solution; it's not mine. My *point*, though, is that if a newer Windows version changes the namespace, it's because the format has changed such that tag structure you're expecting wouldn't be found even if you were ignoring the default namespace. If they don't change that part of the structure, they'd probably introduce another namespace for the newer tags, similar to how .manifest files have evolved over Windows versions since XP.

Comment: The issue is "UTF-16".  To fix I use StreamReader : StreamReader sReader = new StreamReader(taskFile); sReader.ReadLine(); var xdoc = XDocument.Load(sReader) which reads the "UTF-16" and them processes the rest of the xml.

Comment: thanks @jdweng, that does not seem to make any difference, how do you read the actual `Command` ?

Answer (score 1):

Check this code..

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(taskFile).Document.ToString();
xdoc = xdoc.Replace("version=\"1.2\" xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windows/2004/02/mit/task\"", "");

XmlDocument xd = new XmlDocument();
xd.LoadXml(xdoc);

var el1 = xd.SelectSingleNode("Task/Actions/Exec/Command");
```

Comment: Thanks @Nahid, I understand your solution and it will work however string editing the XML before parsing it seems to me like the wrong approach

Comment: It's just too heavy handed .. a good solution will make the parsing deal with the namespace correctly (in this case ignore it), not modify the XML before parsing. Also your solution needs to load the entire XML as string before parsing which is not great. See my solution in the EDIT in the question which is IMO better though I'm not happy with that as well.